# How do I hook into IDP initiated single logout to run custom code?

Tags: sustainsys-saml2

I'm using sustainsys.saml2.httpmodule. I would like to run some code to log the logout from an IDP initiated single log out. The user also does not seem to be logged out (IsAuthenticated is still true) after an IDP initiated single log out even though https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/Logout gives me a success result.

I can't seem to find anyone else needing the same functionality or having the same issues. My Sustainsys config is below.

```
<sustainsys.saml2 entityId="http://localhost:53758/Saml2"
                returnUrl="http://localhost:53758/Common/Pages/Saml2Login.aspx"
                authenticateRequestSigningBehavior="IfIdpWantAuthnRequestsSigned"
                validateCertificates="false"
                publicOrigin ="http://localhost:53758/">
    <nameIdPolicy allowCreate="false" format="Unspecified"/>
    <metadata cacheDuration="PT1440M" wantAssertionsSigned="true">
        <organization name="ab" displayName="ab" url="https://www.example.com/" language="en" />
        <contactPerson type="Technical" email="a@b.com" />
        <requestedAttributes>
            <add friendlyName ="Some Name" name="urn:someName" nameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri" isRequired="true" />
        </requestedAttributes>
    </metadata>
    <identityProviders>
    <add entityId="https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/Metadata"
        signOnUrl="https://stubidp.sustainsys.com"
        logoutUrl="https://stubidp.sustainsys.com/Logout"
        allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true"
        binding="HttpRedirect"
        wantAuthnRequestsSigned="true">
        <signingCertificate storeName="CertificateAuthority" storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                        findValue="cdf7090a433561a843b51198b0ba6456" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" />
    </add>
    </identityProviders>
    <serviceCertificates>
        <add storeName="CertificateAuthority" storeLocation="CurrentUser" findValue="2cfe21cb930c19a341e9e30a07a3c123" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" />
    </serviceCertificates>
</sustainsys.saml2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `LogoutCommandResultCreated` notification. It will get called both when the redirect to the Idp is about to happen as well as after the response has been received from the Idp.

Comment: I can't see anyway that I can get to the specific information sent in that request. The CommandResult argument only gives the requested page and querystring through the Location property, everything else is null. Is it safe to say that with an IDP initiated SLO, I'll always be within context and able to use HttpContext.Current.User.Claims? What if the user does IDP initiated SLO from a different PC than the one they used to log in to the SP in question, would the SP not logging out because of no context be OK?

Comment: Also I was able to get single Logout to actually log the user out but I had to add IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SignOut() and FormsAuthentication.SignOut() in the LogoutCommandResultCreated handler.